# Read multiple txt files and sort them out android

Tags: java, android, file, find, storage

I got a little problem.
I got a map (on android phone) called "Save", in that folder I got several .txt files.

I know how to enter the folder, and I can read 1 txt file (hardcoded) but I want it to be dynamic.

I want somehting like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

             File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

             save = root.toString()+"/Save/";

                if (save.startsWith("3_test")){
                    System.out.println("FOUND!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("NOT FOUND!");
                }

        }
```

I got a txt file called 3_test.txt but he can't find it this way, if I do it hardcoded it does find it.

The problem is that I don't know how to "scan" all files in the folder Save and then put an "if" check over it.

Hope someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code won't work in Java either: your `save` variable contais the path to the folder Save, under de `root` folder.
To achieve a filtered directory listing, you can try using the list() method on the File object for the Save folder, passing a custom [`java.io.FilenameFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) implementation, so it will scan the whole content of the target folder, and returning only the names of the files that match your constraint:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

         File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
         File saveFolder= new File(root, "Save");

         String[] files=saveFolder.list(
            new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                //define here you filter condition for every single file
                    return name.startsWith("3_test");

                }
            });

         if(files.length>0) {
             System.out.println("FOUND!");
         } else {
             System.out.println("NOT FOUND!");
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `save` a `File` rather than a dumb `String`, then you can call `listFiles()` on it which returns an array of the `File`s in the directory. You can then iterate over the array.

```
File save = new File(root, "Save");

for (File f : save.listFiles()) {
    // check each file
    if (f.getName().startWith("3_test.txt") {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `listFiles()` to get all child files of any directory and use `file.getName()` to get name of the file.

**Example**

```
String folderName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String folderNameStr = "Save";
    File destDir = new File(folderName+"/"+folderNameStr);
    File[] childFiles =destDir.listFiles();
    String childFileName = null;
    for(File child: childFiles){
        childFileName = child.getName();
        if(!childFileName.equals("3_test")){
            // do your task
        }
        System.out.println(childFileName);
    }
```